# How to avoid redundant code for session check with nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express

i am working with express module.

For each route, i put this code (except for the login/sign-up page)

```
if (req.session.user!='admin')
{
   res.redirect('/');
   return ;
}
```

Is there a way to tell express to automatcly call this session check, except for one specific route (login page) ?
Because this gave me redundant code, and there is a risk to forget to put this check for new routes...

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways:

- global `app.use` with condition (`if(req.url === 'login/sign-up')  ...` )
- two different routers for login/sign-up and all others. And apply middleware for router
- middleware for each router (the worst approach, imho)

**UPDATE**

From http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
  next();
});
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page');
});
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.send('About birds');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then just call `app.use(router)`. Bescides, using router is a good idea because it allow to group routes by what they mean and work with it as like it module

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me more about applying middleware on router ?

Comment: @testpresta See update. Router with that middleware have to contains all routes except login/sign-up

Comment: Thanks very much but when you say if(req.url === 'login/sign-up'), is there a way to check from route pattern instead of raw url ?

Comment: @testpresta You can use regexp to test requested url

Comment: there is no way to get the route name ?

Comment: there is no route name when you use `app.use`. It will handle every request to the server if no one upper middleware inerrupt request

Comment: i'm sorry. It seems like you can use routes in `app.use`. So you can just use regep as the rout template and avoid `if` inside midleware

Answer (score 0):

`Middleware` can do your thing, take a example for a certain route :

```
route.get('/somelink',function(res,res,next){
if (req.session.user!='admin')
{
   res.redirect('/');
  }else{
next();
}
},function(req,res){
res.render('page');

});
```

Notive that you can even separate callback functions to allow **reusability** :

```
route.get('/somelink',check,function(req,res){
   res.render('page');
});

function check(req,res,next){
if (req.session.user!='admin')
{
   res.redirect('/');
}else{
  next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) :

```
// middleware.js
module.export = (req, res, next) => {
  // check session or whatever...
  return next();
};
```

then simply use it when needed :

```
// server.js
const app = expres();
app.use('/path', require('./middleware.js'));
```